# R Markdown - Vertical Text Alignment with Inline Images with Latex PDF

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, xelatex

I'm trying to create an R Markdown script to routinely export PDF reports of data and I'm struggling with the most basic formatting tasks here!

First of all I just want to create a page header with a left-aligned title and a right-aligned organisation logo on the same line; the logo is approximately 2-line heights, so I also want to top-align the title. In HTML/CSS this would be like a 10 second task, but I've been struggling with this all morning!

So this is my current effort:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
geometry: margin=1.5cm
papersize: a4
pagestyle: empty
fontsize: 12 pt 
---

<!-- Inline But No Scaling or Alignment   -->
# Left Aligned Title ![](C:/logo.png){ height=65px }

<!-- Aligned but Not Compatible with Inline Title -->
```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.align='right', out.height='8%'}
knitr::include_graphics("C:/logo.png")
```
````

I even tried separating into columns but couldn't get it to work. Just wondering if there's any easy way to achieve this format, with a left & top aligned title and a right aligned logo in R Markdown.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use LaTeX commands, like `minipage` to create two spaces side by side, one for the title and one for the image. In the example below, I replaced `pdf_document` by `bookdown::pdf_document2:` to show that this solution allows section numbering:

````
---
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    toc: false
geometry: margin=1.5cm
papersize: a4
pagestyle: empty
fontsize: 12 pt 
---

\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
\section{Left Aligned Title}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
```{r, echo=FALSE, fig.align='right', out.height='8%'}
knitr::include_graphics("logo.png")
```
\end{minipage}
````

Comment: Thanks... this is exactly what I tried when I mentioned that "I tried separating into columns" but must not have had the syntax quite right, but your example works brilliantly.